# Failed 400. Error code on Eternl

Tags: cardano-address, error, eternl

Trying to figure out why I can’t cancel a limit order I put on Eternl wallet app. For some reason when I try to cancel it tells me Failed 400. I’ve tried everything I can think of with no success.

Comment: Please provide more information, otherwise it's hard to help you. On which exchange/DEX are you trying to cancel the trade? Do you have sufficient funds on your wallet? Do you have a collateral UTxO set up? Are you using single address mode? Is the error from the DEX or from Eternl itself? A screenshot of the error would help too.